# What strategy is working against Geth Primes?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Missiles, drones and turrets oh my!

What can we do as a squad to handle Geth Prime opponents before we get creamed?

Is it true that you can shoot down their missile?  Is there any particular weapon requirement for that?

Comment: [Comedy Option.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5rRZdiu1UE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, follow these rules.

- Avoid taking them on by yourself.
- Keep a reasonable distance away and in cover.
- Use hit and run tactics
- Leave them for last if at all possible.
- Focus fire, Focus fire, Focus fire
- If all else fails, use a Cobra Missle Launcher

These tactics work equally well for Brutes, Banshees, and Atlases.

Comment: Any word on missile interception?

Comment: @fedley  I've never been able to do it. I'm skeptical of the possibility to do it.  If someone comments saying they have, I'll add it to the ansser.

Comment: I've done it to rockets from a Geth Rocket Trooper, but it was pure luck. It's pretty goddamned hard to do deliberately. I'm don't believe it works on Primes, as IIRC, their weapons are not mechanically similar.

Answer (score 2):

Energy Drain at max rank will completely kill a Prime's shields, unlike Overload ranked for max damage. Reave, combined with high-powered sniper fire, Incinerate, and/or Warp, will easily kill him once he's stripped down to armor.

However, Chain Overload will easily deal with his Combat Drone, but you will need to watch out for the turret he'll toss around.

Also, Primes use a Plasma Cannon, so I'm not entirely sure you can "shoot it down."

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that they fire 3 shots and then pause before firing more. If you can get rid of its drone and turret, it wastes time summoning them again. Hammer into it when its not firing, you and your team can do a nice bit of damage before it fires again.

Simple stuff but I hope its useful